# Some lines ending with ";1" in Rails legacy code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, legacy-code, suffix

Hey Stack Overflow fellows,

I need your help on this one. For a few months now I'm dealing with Ruby on Rails application that is mostly Legacy. Today, I noticed the weirdest thing about the codebase. Some files, not many but the significant ones, contain a few lines of code that would end up with `; 1`. Like for example: `Users.find(id); 1`. Occurrence of those suffixes does not create any form of the pattern. Sometimes is `; 1` appears after `puts` or after expression that will always return value e.g. `nil || 'default_value'; 1`.

Does it make any sense to use the suffix? Is there any reason behind this? Maybe there used to be a tool that worked with Ruby code and `; 1` was form of annotation. I would gladly remove the suffix but I want to make sure that it's 100% safe.

Here is a code sample from the project added in the same commit:

```
times = events.map{|x| [x.time, x.time_from_impression_id]};1
times = times.map{|x| (x.first - x.last) / 1.day}.sort;1
time_to_event_success = times[(times.length.to_f * 0.95).to_i]
events = events.select{|e| e.time_from_impression_id < time_to_event_success.days.ago};1
```

Comment: That's on old legacy (bad) perl-ism. Didn't know people used to do it in ruby as well.

Comment: _"does not create any form of the pattern"_ – in the code you've posted, `;1` seems to appear on intermediate steps or lines which return (large?) arrays.

Comment: This code needs a bath because there's a lot of confusion in there. Hope you can refactor this into something easier to read.

Answer (score 6):

Semi-colons in ruby terminate statements in the same manner as a line break. The `; 1` really isn't doing anything useful.

Logically the code you posted is equivalent to:

```
times = events.map{|x| [x.time, x.time_from_impression_id]}
1
times = times.map{|x| (x.first - x.last) / 1.day}.sort
1
time_to_event_success = times[(times.length.to_f * 0.95).to_i]
events = events.select{|e| e.time_from_impression_id < 
time_to_event_success.days.ago}
1
```

The only thing I can think of is that if someone was testing the code out in IRB adding the `; 1` to the end of a line would prevent the return value of the previous statement from echoing. That or they didn't quite understand how implicit return and truthy and falsy values work in ruby.

Comment: Suppressing IRB output seems reasonable. I can't think of another reason.

Comment: @Stefan: yep, this was the first thing on my mind. I do it all the time. Only I use `; true`